# Java spring: erro em remover objeto de listagem de model

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, spring, model

Estou com problemas na construção das relações entre os modelos de um projeto, eu tenho um documento que tem várias subcategorias.

Quando eu salvo um documento quero fazer uma validação, que criará a relação *subcategoria-documento* no campo `document` que este modelo possui, mas estou tendo problemas.
Suprimi parte do código para apontar exatamente onde acontece o problema, que acompanhei no debug.

**Document.java**

```
...

@OneToMany(mappedBy="document", cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
private Set<Subcategory> subcategories;
```

**Subcategory.java**

```
...
@ManyToOne()
//necessário, pois se remover isso ao listar o documento ele entra num loop entre as referencias de documento-subcategoria e subcategoria-documento
@JsonIgnore()
private Document document;
```

**DocumentServiceImp.java**

```
...

//primeiro chamo a função do save, passando um objeto do tipo documento, e assim irá para a função validade
public Document save(document model) {
return repository.saveAndFlush(validade(model));
}

public Document validade(Document model) {
for(Subcategory subcategory:model.getSubcategories()) {
//pego o objeto 
            subcategory = subcategoryService.findById(subcategory.getId());

//adiciono uma referência do documento na subcategoria
            subcategory.setDocument(model);

//após isso, quero atualizar no modelo de subcategoria esse objeto que adicionei o documento (o do for)
//para isso eu removo o objeto antigo da subcategoria do modelo, entanto isso retorna false, nada é removido mesmo existindo na listagem de subcategorias
            model.getSubcategories().remove(subcategory.getId());
//adiciono novamente o objeto atualizado, o objeto fica duplicado, dá erro, o antigo sem o documento e o novo com o documento.
            model.addSubcategory(subcategory);
        }
}
```

Sem criar esse vínculo entre *documento-subcategoria* e *subcategoria-documento*, não consigo associar corretamente estes.

Qualquer contribuição é válida.

Comment: Essa parte do validate esta confusa,

Comment: Bom,você não precisa executar a busca do document pelo id, basta adicionar o objeto de referencia, até pq se o resultado for nulo, a subcategoria sera salva sem o document

Comment: Eu vi que você manda remover a categoria pelo id, antes de mandar salvar o document, não entendi o porque, mas acho que você deve mudar a logica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `remove` está retornando false porque ele não conseguiu achar um objeto na coleção que atendesse ao `equals`. De acordo com o Javadoc:

> Removes the specified element from this set if it is present (optional operation). More formally, removes an element e such that **(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))**, if this set contains such an element. Returns true if this set contained the element (or equivalently, if this set changed as a result of the call). (This set will not contain the element once the call returns.)

Você pode utilizar o [removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
model.getSubcategories().removeIf(subcat => subcat.getId() == subcategory.getId());
```